# In GTK (C++ Version), how to make a box bigger than others?

Tags: c++, gtk

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  GtkWidget *pWindow;
  GtkWidget *pVBox;
  GtkWidget *pEntry;
  GtkWidget *pButton;
  GtkWidget *pLabel;
  GtkWidget *text_view;
  GtkWidget *scrollbar;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  pWindow = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(pWindow), "My IRC");
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(pWindow), 800, 600);
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(pWindow), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  pVBox = gtk_vbox_new(TRUE, 0);
  pEntry = gtk_entry_new();
  pLabel = gtk_label_new(NULL);
  text_view = gtk_text_new(NULL, NULL);
  scrollbar = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);

  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(pWindow), pVBox);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(pVBox), scrollbar, TRUE, FALSE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(pVBox), pEntry, TRUE, FALSE, 0);
  gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(scrollbar), text_view);

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(pEntry), "activate", G_CALLBACK(on_activate_entry), (GtkWidget*) text_view);

  gtk_widget_show_all(pWindow);

  gtk_main();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I want to make the `text_view` box bigger than the other one.  I couldn't find any solutions in the GTK documentation.

PS: It's GTK 2.0.

Comment: Would you like the text view to fill the window, shoving the entry at the bottom?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I want !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two boolean arguments of `gtk_box_pack_start()` are `expand` and `fill`. When `expand` is true, the widget gets extra space after allocating other widgets. When `fill` is true, the widget is *resized* to fill that space. So what you want to do instead is

```
  // expand AND fill - fills all available space
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(pVBox), scrollbar, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
  // NO expand AND NO fill - only uses what it needs
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(pVBox), pEntry, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
```

[Here's a page with more information.](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch29s02.html) Note that you can use the `[hv](expand|align)` properties with boxes as well as grids (and use `gtk_container_add()`, which acts like `gtk_box_pack_start()`).